# can we install kernel module with make file

Tags: makefile, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, insmod

I have working kernel module which I install manually with insmod/modprobe command as learnt by reading book. however I was wondering if there is way to do it automatically after compiling - So basically how to automate **insmod/modprobe** command ?

My modprobe has a dependent file thread_module.o as well

My make file so far

```
obj-m := wakeup_counter.o
obj-m += thread_module.o
$INSTALL_MOD_PATH = /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build M=$(PWD) modules

install:
    make $(INSTALL_MOD_PATH) =/build modules_install
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

output after running : make install

```
root@xyz:/home/xyz/Desktop/Drivers/symbols# make install
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build M=/home/xyz/Desktop/Drivers/symbols modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64'
  INSTALL /home/xyz/Desktop/Drivers/symbols/thread_module.ko
  INSTALL /home/xyz/Desktop/Drivers/symbols/wakeup_counter.ko
  DEPMOD  2.6.32-5-amd64
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64'
```

Edit: After going through comments and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt I tried to add install command but I dont see any modules in the build path - Also at high level I get what we write in cmd prompt we type in Makefile but if someone can give an example it would help me to understand with nice base case to refer.

Comment: Installing software is usually performed by `make install` command. Just create "install" target in your makefile and place all needed actions in its recipes.

Comment: Yes, and call `make … modules_install` from it.

Comment: Any command that you can run in the command shell, you can add that action as rules for a target in makefile.

Comment: @Tsyvarev : I tried but seems I am doing something wrong - I have updated the post with relevant information

Comment: @AndyShevchenko - I tried can u see what I am doing wrong

Comment: @cm161 : Thanks, but there is associated grammer with Makefile which is causing problem in getting it to work

Comment: `I dont see any modules in the build path` - you cannot find your modules under `/home/xyz/Desktop/Drivers/symbols`? According to your output of `make install` they should exist. As for installed path, it is `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/extra/`. BTW, you post makefile with very strange definition of `INSTALL_MOD_PATH` variable (`$` sign in definition string) and receipt of `install` target (`=/build`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev - sorry for using wrong terminology with line I dont see any modules - I guess a newbie sign .. what I meant was after doing make install I expected them to be present after I do lsmod - I did see .ko files in my folder - however with steps pointed by cm161 - i was able to cross the hurdle - thanks for all the pointers - appreciate it !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj-m := wakeup_counter.o
obj-m += thread_module.o

KDIR = /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Example of command shell instruction being used as rule in Makefile:

```
install:
    modprobe wakeup_counter
    modprobe thread_module
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - there was small change that I needed to make instead of modules_install - i had to change it to modules ..but with your steps pointed out I understand things better .. thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Enhancing the answer posted by @cm161 for future users to highlight exact steps which worked for me

With below Makefile use following steps

Step 1:  make ( type just make command) - for creation of modules i.e. .ko files and associated files

Step 2: make install

Step 3 : now do lsmod you should be able to see new modules

```
obj-m := wakeup_counter.o
obj-m += thread_module.o

KDIR = /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
    cp wakeup_counter.ko /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/
    cp thread_module.ko /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/

install:
    modprobe wakeup_counter
    modprobe thread_module

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: You can automate copying of .ko files through the makefile by adding 'cp' rules for 'all' target as follows: all:<NEWLINE><TAB>make ....<NEWLINE><TAB>cp wakeup_counter.ko $(DEST_DIR)/.<NEWLINE><TAB>cp thread_module.ko $(DEST_DIR)/.    where DEST_DIR = /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64